# Ignite and Kafka Integration

Tags: ignite

I am trying the Ignite and Kafka Integration to bring kafka message into Ignite cache.

My message key is a random string(To work with Ignite, the kafka message key can't be null), and the value is a json string representation for Person(a java class)

When Ignite receives such a message, it looks that Ignite will use the message's key(the random string in my case) as the cache key.

Is it possible to change the message key to the person's id, so that I can put the  into the cache.

Looks that `streamer.receiver(new StreamReceiver)` is workable

```
        streamer.receiver(new StreamReceiver<String, String>() {
            public void receive(IgniteCache<String, String> cache, Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries) throws IgniteException {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entries) {
                    Person p = fromJson(entry.getValue());
                    //ignore the message key,and use person id as the cache key
                    cache.put(p.getId(), p);
                }
            }
        });
```

Is this the recommended way? and I am not sure whether calling cache.put in StreamReceiver is a correct way, since it is only a pre-processing step before writing to cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data streamer will map all your keys to cache affinity nodes, create batches of entries and send batches to affinity nodes. After it `StreamReceiver` will receive your entries, get `Person`'s ID and invoke `cache.put(K, V)`. Putting entry lead to mapping your key to corresponding cache affinity node and sending update request to this node.

Everything looks good. But result of mapping your random key from Kafka and result of mapping `Person`'s ID will be different (most likely different nodes). As result your will get poor performance due to redundant network hops.

Unfortunately, current `KafkaStreamer` implementations doesn't support stream tuple extractors (see e.g. `StreamSingleTupleExtractor` class). But you can easily create your own Kafka streamer implementation using existing one as example.

Also you can try use `KafkaStreamer`'s `keyDecoder` and `valDecoder` in order to extract `Person`'s ID from Kafka message. I don't sure, but it can help.

Comment: Thanks @a_gura for the helpful answer!